# Spring Netflix LoadBalancing rules comparison

Tags: spring, spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a question regarding to client-side load balancing with Spring-Cloud Netflix.

When load balancing is enabled, Ribbon will choose a server to be called. The choosing rule depends on IRule implementation which is chosen.

What is the difference between following implementations:

- `AvailabilityFilteringRule`
- `BestAvailableRule`
- `ClientConfigEnabledRoundRobinRule`
- `RoundRobinRule`
- `WeightedResponseTimeRule`
- `ZoneAvoidanceRule`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you looked here https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers#common-rules? There are some descriptions.

Comment: @spencergibb some descriptions, others incomplete, others missing. This question is very valid and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[visit source](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/tree/master/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer) for more info, and for different rules.

**RoundRobinRule**
This rule simply choose servers by round robin. It is often used as the default rule or fallback of more advanced rules.

**BestAvailableRule**
A rule that skips servers with "tripped" circuit breaker and picks the
server with lowest concurrent requests.

**AvailabilityFilteringRule**
This rule will skip servers that are deemed "circuit tripped" or with high concurrent connection count.

**WeightedResponseTimeRule**
For this rule, each server is given a weight according to its average response time. The longer the response time, the less weight it will get. The rule randomly picks a server where the possibility is determined by server's weight.

choose one using property

```
  service-id:
    ribbon:
      NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule
```